# How to use jQuery on() when a element is "ready" rather than an event received?

Tags: jquery, events

I'm trying to build a half-transparent menu (and other things), the codes look like this:

```
    $(".hover-opaque").on({
        load: function () {
            $(this).addClass("opacity02");
        },
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).removeClass("opacity02");
            $(this).addClass("opacity1");
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).removeClass("opacity1");
            $(this).addClass("opacity02");
        }
    });
```

When it's loaded (or, "ready"), addClass("opacity02") to make it half transparent, and when a mouse entered, make it opaque by addClass("opacity1"), and when mouse leave, do the opposite side again.

So far mouseenter and mouseleave work well, but "load"(or "ready") does not work.
Of course i can do it by this:

```
    $(".hover-opaque").addClass("opacity02");
```

but i heard that it cannot deal with Ajax-generated contents.

So what's the problem?

By the way, I tried putting the above mention codes in document.ready() and not, but both did not work.

I checked lots of samples of jquery.on(),  but all of them are about handling "click" "mouseenter" or other events.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Note that only the document has a ready handler, and only certain elements has a load event, mainly elements that load external resources. As for dynamically added elements, that's not the way to handle those either. As you're the one inserting the elements, you should already know when they are inserted and act accordingly, only in rare cases are other solutions neccessary, and the way to solve the event handler problems, is with delegated event handlers.

Comment: Yes you have the point. Since I'm quite new in JS, seems I ignored some basic knowledge, ha. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @adeneo said, "ready" event works only for document. And any manipulation of DOM should be done after document is ready. So all your code should reside inside `$(document).ready` (unless your JavaScript is inline after the HTML, which is a bad practice).

Then you can add your class to your `.hover-opaque` element. No need for individual "ready" event for it.

For example:

```
$(function() { // shorthand for $(document).ready
  $(".hover-opaque").addClass("opacity02").on({
    //...your events...
  });
});
```